# How do I implement a "Submit" button on a Javascript/HTML calculation form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to add a "Submit" button in order to execute the formula after submit is pressed, but I can't seem to connect the submit button to the code to make the total emissions update only when the button is pressed.

When you input a vehicle type and miles driven and press somewhere else on the page, the total emissions updates. I'm trying to implement a 'submit' or 'calculate' button so that the total emissions only updates when the button is clicked.

I'd also like to wrap the Javascript in a function rather than window.onload, but I'm not sure how to implement that either.

```js
 window.onload = function () {
        var carType = document.getElementById('VehicleType');
  var total = document.getElementById('totalEmissions');
  var miles = document.getElementById('milesDriven');
        
        carType.onchange = function(){
          if(miles.value){
            total.value = parseFloat(carType.value) * parseFloat(miles.value);
          }
          if(!miles.value || !carType.value){
             total.value = "";
          }
        };
   
  miles.onchange = function () {
            if(miles.value && carType.value){
              total.value = parseFloat(carType.value) * parseFloat(miles.value)
            }
            if(!miles.value || !carType.value){
              total.value = "";
            }
  };  
};
```

```html
<strong>Car Type</strong></th><br>
    <select name="VehicleType" id="VehicleType">
      <option value="">Select an option…</option>
      <option value="552">Sprinter Van</option>
      <option value="444">Personal Car</option>
      <option value="444">Renter Car</option>
      <option value="140">Bus or Shuttle</option>
      <option value="727">Diesel Truck</option>
      <option value="683">Regular Truck</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<strong>Miles Driven</strong></th><br>
    <td width="65"><input type="text" name="milesDriven" id="milesDriven" size="15" maxlength="5"/></td>
    <td width="43">miles</td>
<br><br>

<strong>Total CO2 Emissions (grams)</strong><br>
    <td><input type="text" name="totalEmissions" id="totalEmissions" size="15" maxlength="5"/></td>
```

Comment: Submit buttons are for submitting form data to a server. If you are just looking for a button to trigger an operation on the page, a regular button or any other clickable element will do (You can turn a `div` into a button quite easily). Additionally, your HTML is invalid. You can't just use `td` elements sporadically on your page. They are part of a `table` element hierarchy. And, you should only use tables to represent tabular data. If you just want a grid-like layout, use CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not a submit button, but a regular `<button>` element. Just create one, give it an `id`, then listen for its `click` event, instead of `change` events of the other two elements. Check for validity inside the function that you execute when it's clicked and show the result, like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var carType = document.getElementById('VehicleType');
  var total = document.getElementById('totalEmissions');
  var miles = document.getElementById('milesDriven');
  var calculateButton = document.getElementById('calculateButton');
  calculateButton.addEventListener('click', calculate);

  function calculate() {
    if (miles.value && carType.value) {
      total.value = parseFloat(carType.value) * parseFloat(miles.value);
    }
    if (!miles.value || !carType.value) {
      total.value = "";
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<strong>Car Type</strong><br>
<select name="VehicleType" id="VehicleType">
      <option value="">Select an option…</option>
      <option value="552">Sprinter Van</option>
      <option value="444">Personal Car</option>
      <option value="444">Renter Car</option>
      <option value="140">Bus or Shuttle</option>
      <option value="727">Diesel Truck</option>
      <option value="683">Regular Truck</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<strong>Miles Driven</strong><br>
<input type="text" name="milesDriven" id="milesDriven" size="15" maxlength="5" />&nbsp;miles
<br><br>

<strong>Total CO2 Emissions (grams)</strong><br><input type="text" name="totalEmissions" id="totalEmissions" size="15" maxlength="5" />
<br><br>

<button id="calculateButton">Calculate</button>
```

**Note 1:** As @ScottMarcus pointed out in the comments, instead of using `onXyz`, it's better to use `.addEventListener(eventName, callback)`.

**Note 2:** I would suggest rechecking your HTML, if this is not part of something bigger, as there are a few problems I can see (which I fixed in my snippet). The [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) is a great place to check for problems in your markup.

Comment: The event isn't actually `onclick`, it's just `click`. You are suggesting and using an older paradigm of setting up the event handling function via the DOM object's `onXyz` event property (not the same thing as the actual event). But, that shouldn't really be used anymore. Instead, use modern standards of `.addEventListener(eventName, callback)`

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for the heads up. I already improved my answer to use modern standards!